# Unable to create new controller in Phalcon

Tags: controller, phalcon

I'm doing the tutorial 2 of Phalcon, with the Demo INVO.
I'm trying to create a new Controller called 'alarm'.
I already created 'AlarmController.php' in /controllers/, I created the view 'alarm.volt' in /views/ and set public 'alarm' with the action 'index' in the SecurityPlugin.php. Someone could do something like this with success?
Starting with Phalcon, without "INVO" I'm having no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. You have to delete all the cookies related to INVO app.

Since you are using the SecurityPlugin, all data of privileges are saved in the cookies, even though you are not logging in on the website.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you! I deleted the cookies of the browser and my website is running :D